# Epochs and Iterations in Deeplearning4j

Tags: deep-learning, deeplearning4j

I recently started learning Deeplearning4j and I fail to understand how the concept of epochs and iterations is actually implemented.
In the online documentation it says:

> an epoch is a complete pass through a given dataset ...
>   Not to be confused with an iteration, which is simply one 
>   update of the neural net model’s parameters.

I ran a training using a MultipleEpochsIterator, but for the first run I set 1 epoch, miniBatchSize = 1 and a dataset of 1000 samples, so I expected the training to finish after 1 epoch and 1000 iterations, but after more than 100.000 iterations it was still running.

```
int nEpochs = 1;
int miniBatchSize = 1;

MyDataSetFetcher fetcher = new MyDataSetFetcher(xDataDir, tDataDir, xSamples, tSamples);
//The same batch size set here was set in the model
BaseDatasetIterator baseIterator = new BaseDatasetIterator(miniBatchSize, sampleSize, fetcher);

MultipleEpochsIterator iterator = new MultipleEpochsIterator(nEpochs, baseIterator);
model.fit(iterator)
```

Then I did more tests changing the batch size, but that didn't change the frequency of the log lines printed by the IterationListener. I mean that I thought that if I increase the batch size to 100 then with 1000 samples I would have just 10 updates of the parameters an therefore just 10 iterations, but the logs and the timestamp intervals are more or less the same.

BTW. There is a similar question, but the answer does not actually answer my question, I would like to understand better the actual details:
[Deeplearning4j: Iterations, Epochs, and ScoreIterationListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637150/deeplearning4j-iterations-epochs-and-scoreiterationlistener)

Comment: I think your answer can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752626/epoch-vs-iteration-when-training-neural-networks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of this will matter after 1.x (which is already out in alpha) - we got rid of iterations long ago.

Originally it was meant to be shortcut syntax so folks wouldn't have to write for loops.

Just focus on for loops with epochs now.