# "How to fix 'Cannot resolve method "iterations and getFeatureMatrix "'?

Tags: dl4j

" I'm new in neural networks and DL4j, and I want to train neural network with CSV and build linear regression. How can I fix these errors "Cannot resolve method'.iterations and getFeatureMatrix()'"?

---

"Previously I'm tried to do that, but have another error in 'seed'".

```
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.RecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.CSVRecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.split.FileSplit;
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.api.OptimizationAlgorithm;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.MultiLayerConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.Updater;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.DenseLayer;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.OutputLayer;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.weights.WeightInit;
import org.deeplearning4j.optimize.listeners.ScoreIterationListener;
import org.nd4j.evaluation.classification.Evaluation;
import org.nd4j.linalg.activations.Activation;
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.DataSet;
import org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.iterator.DataSetIterator;
import org.nd4j.linalg.lossfunctions.LossFunctions;
import java.io.File;






public class Data {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

### Parameters:

```
        int seed = 3000;
        int batchSize = 200;
        double learningRate = 0.001;
        int nEpochs = 150;
        int numInputs = 2;
        int numOutputs = 2;
        int numHiddenNodes = 100;
```

### Load data:

```
        //load data train
        RecordReader rr = new CSVRecordReader();
        rr.initialize(new FileSplit(new File("train.csv")));
        DataSetIterator trainIter = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(rr, batchSize, 0, 2);

        //load test data

        RecordReader rrTest = new CSVRecordReader();
        rr.initialize(new FileSplit(new File("test.csv")));


        DataSetIterator testIter = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(rrTest, batchSize, 0, 2);
```

#### Network Configuration:

```
        MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
                .seed(seed)
                .iterations(1000)
                .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT)
                .learningRate(learningRate)
                .updater(Updater.NESTEROVS).momentum(0.9)
                .list()
                .layer(0, new DenseLayer.Builder()
                        .nIn(numInputs)
                        .nOut(numHiddenNodes)
                        .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                        .activation(Activation.fromString("relu"))
                        .build())
                .layer(1, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
                        .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                        .activation(Activation.fromString("softmax"))
                        .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                        .nIn(numHiddenNodes)
                        .nOut(numOutputs)
                        .build()
                )
                .pretrain(false).backprop(true).build();

        MultiLayerNetwork model = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
        model.init();
        model.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener((15)));
        for (int n = 0; n < nEpochs; n++) {
            model.fit((trainIter));
            System.out.println(("--------------eval model"));
            Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(numOutputs);
            while (testIter.hasNext()) {
                DataSet t = testIter.next();
                INDArray features = getFeatureMatrix();
                INDArray lables = t.getLabels();
                INDArray predicted = model.output(features, false);
                eval.eval(lables, predicted);
            }
            System.out.println(eval.stats());
        }
    }
}
```

### Logs

[Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOBds.png)

Comment: May we ask you to provide some log of running / building process ?

Comment: @bastienenjalbert  Of course I have already added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should consider to use more class (like one for the definition of the neural network, one for the training process etc, ...). Just a best practice stuff.

I do not know which version of DL4J you're using but we can notice that *getFeatureMatrix()* [has been removed](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/pull/6006/commits/5040de6ca0dfa414033a23dcfce750465003b261). One more thing is that this function should be called on a DataSet object and not "statically" like you seem to do. (you should do `t.getFeatureMatrix()`).

It is pretty same things about iterations() function of the neural network creation; This function [has been removed](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/pull/4326) since some DL4J releases. You can get more information about this function [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637150/deeplearning4j-iterations-epochs-and-scoreiterationlistener). Now you have to find an alternative to set up number of iteration, you can take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273031/epochs-and-iterations-in-deeplearning4j). Hope it is answering your question !